# Pointer to Address containing another Address

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have been working on a specific code and this works well in my program. I  wanted someone to confirm if my interpretation is correct. The part I would like to understand in the code below is:

```
UINT8* pData;
pData = (MFG.Ident.MFGName);
```

I had to define a pointer variable of type `pData` and then to gain access to `MFGName` I had to write it as `pData = *&(MFG.Ident.MFGName)`.

**NOTE: `MFG` is a struct which and contains an element `Ident` which is another struct which further contains an element `MFGName` and `MFGName` is an Array. Shown Below**

Is it because `MFG.Ident` is a structure which contains an array and thats why it needs to be accessed this way.
Can it be written any better that what it is?

*IN HEADER FILE* PartName.h

```
#ifndef PartName_H
#define PartName_H 

typedef UINT8 MFGName_Struct_t [10]; //Is an array of 10 x UINT8 elememnts

typedef struct
{
    UINT16 <some variable>;
    MFGName_Struct_t MFGName; //Is an Array of 10 elements of type UINT8
}IDENT_Struct_t;

typedef struct MFG_Struct_t
{
    int8 <some variable>;
    UINT8 <some other variable>;
    IDENT_Struct_t Ident;//Ident struct has 2 members of type UINT16, MFGName_Struct_t 
} MFG_Struct_t;

#endif
```

*IN C FILE* "PartName.c"

```
#include PartName.h
static MFG_Struct_t  MFG; //MFG struct has 3 members of type int8,UINT8,IDENT_Struct_t

const UINT8 Test[3]={0x48, 0x49, 0x4A};
UINT8* pData;
pData = (MFG.Ident.MFGName);
UINT8 CompA;
UINT8 CompB;
         for (i = 0;(i < 3);i++) //Compare only first 3 elements of array
         {
             CompA = *pData;
             CompB = Test[i];
             if (CompA != CompB)
             {
                DO SOMETHING
             }
             else
             {
                DO SOMETHING
             }
             pData++;
         }
```

Comment: `*&` is the same as doing nothing, do you could remove that. It's pretty hard for anyone to answer your question since it does not contain a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you can obtain a pointer to MFGName, you likely can access MFGName elements directly. Perhaps there's some constancy that you are trying to work around, but as per MM's comment: we'd need an [MVCE].

Comment: thanks M.M, your suggestion is good!